# A jquery plugin post toolbar

Tags: jquery-plugins

Does anyone knows about a jquery post's toolbar plugin?  I have a forum and I would like to attach to each post a complete toolbar : reply, delete, send by mail, attach a file...

Best,
Mehdi

Comment: Hi @beni-oui - generally it's Good Form to show us what you've already tried and why it's not working for you.

Comment: Oh, it is not technical problem. Just made a google search to find an integrated complete plugin for a toolbar. But I didn t find. Nevertheless, I am new to stackoverflow, perhaps this is not the right place to post those kind of question

Comment: It's quite ok to post all kinds of question, but I think you're not getting answers because what you have asked is very vague.  I'd suggest asking specific questions. eg - if you need help with how to use this plugin - try asking for whether people know of a good tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: Ok, I ll be watchful about that

Answer (score 1):

Mehdi,

I'm not sure I exactly understand but I recently used these jquery toolbars, perhaps they may help you too.

http://javan.us/jbar/

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2010/05/23/microsoft-office-minibar-jQuery-CSS3.aspx

Comment: Not exactly I am searching for simple tool : like replying, deleting, associating files.... But thanks!